# What is sum of areas of all right triangles in first quadrant of unit circle?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I want to sum the areas of each right triangle formed as a radius sweeps out angles from $0$ to $\pi/2$ radians in the unit circle.  Each triangle's area should be $\frac{1}{2}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$, so I tried integrating this expression with respect to $\theta$, from $0$ to $\pi/2$, and got $1/4$.  But, isn't $1/4$ the area of the single triangle that is formed when $\theta = \pi/4$ ?  Shouldn't the sum of all such triangle areas in the first quadrant be greater than just one of them?

Comment: Sum is not the same thing as integral.

Comment: Even so, I thought that I could find the sum by integration.  Is there a better way?

Comment: You are trying to sum an uncountable infinity of non-zero numbers. Can't be done.

Comment: The sum is not bounded, that is, it is infinite. The integral can be used to determine the 'average' if you like, but there is quite a difference between an average and a sum.

Comment: Interesting.  I have always thought of the integral as a way of summing.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the integral represents the "sum" you want depends on how you construct it.

Roughly speaking, you know that the area of each triangle is $\frac 12 \sin \theta \cos \theta$ - it isn't multiplied by anything small related to $\delta \theta$ - so there isn't an obvious integral lurking in the background. You are adding big things together, not small ones.

Comment: What if I were trying to determine the volume of the solid created by the "trail" left by each triangle area as the entire circle is dragged a distance of one unit while the radius sweeps from 0 to pi/2?  Would an integral be appropriate in that case?

Comment: @CJP: No. Divide up that solid that you want into thin slices and see how thin each slice should be if you have $n$ slices. Then see what is the sum. If the sum exactly matches a Riemann sum, then it will tend to the Riemann integral because the leftover bits have volume tending to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. If it does not match exactly, then you need to make some small algebraic manipulation. You should in the first place expect a constant somewhere because you need to account for how fast you drag the circle compared to how fast you sweep.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect the sum of all real numbers from $0$ to $2$ to be? Certainly it doesn't have any value. On the other hand, $\int_0^2 x\ dx = 2$. The integral is just the area under the graph, which has nothing to do with any kind of sum of the values of the function. The closest you can get is that it is the limit (if it exists) of a weighted sum of the function values with weight being the difference between sampled points, as the sampled points grow closer and closer. In physics, where arguably integration was first used, the things that were integrated come with physical units. If you integrate a length over another length, you get area, not length. Putting lengths together end to end just gives you length, not area. Similarly integrating velocity over time, you get distance, with units of length, not units of velocity. In mathematics we often don't have units but the distinction is often still there, and many times you can expect a purely mathematical formula to be interpretable with units that cancel out.